# How often does Getmonero.org update its source code?

Tags: getmonero-website

After pull requests are [merged](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-site/pulls) on GitHub there is a delay before new content can be seen on the [getmonero.org](https://getmonero.org/)

How often does the website update its source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that Fluffypony updates the website, he is basically the only one that can give you a certain answer. However, usually the site gets updated shortly after the pull requests are merged.